# Printing an array list with duplicate entries

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

Im storing names in a array list logcall and printing them out accordingly. But when there are duplicates how do I only print them once rather than however many times they're in the array list?

```
public static void displayHistory()
{
    for(Call allCalls : logCall) 
    {
        if(logCall!=null)
        {
            String name = allCalls.getName();
            Long phone = allCalls.getPhoneNumber();
            String type = allCalls.getType();
            String time = allCalls.getTime();
            String date = allCalls.getDate();

            String phoneStr = Long.toString(phone);

            if(name.equals("N/A"))
            {
                System.out.println( PhoneBook.formatNum(phoneStr) + " (" + type + ") " +date + " " + time);
            }
            else if(search(name) > 1)
            {
                System.out.println( name + " (" +search(name)+ ") " );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( name + " (" + type + ") " + date + " " + time);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick thought I had would be to store your output in a string and use the string's .contains method to search for duplicates before adding a new entry. Then you would just print the output string at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashSet`. This is far more efficient than checking it in a string as Logan Kulinski says, as checking in a string takes N operations, and the complexity will be N^2.

For example,

```
Collection<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();

for (.....) {    //process the items here
    //format the stuff and what not
    if (!seen.contains(currentString)) {
        seen.add(currentString);
        print(currentString);
}
```

Comment: You can replace `if (!seen.contains(currentString))` with `if(seen.add(currentString))` and then you will only need the `print` statement in the if statement body. `add` returns true/false on whether the operation succeeded